# What does a single variable name mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In some code, I found:

```
class Job
  @@types = [:a, :b, :c, :d].reduce({}) do |acc, cmd|
    acc[cmd] = cmd.to_s
    acc
  end
  # ...
end
```

1. There's nothing passed into `reduce`. What does that mean?
2. There's a single `acc`. What does that mean?

Comment: _"There's nothing passed into reduce"_ – what do you mean by that? `{}` is being passed into `reduce` and an empty hash is not nothing.

Comment: I think you need to spend a little time learning about basic data types in ruby... `nil`, `false`, `[]`, `""`, `{}`, ... are all different, well defined, objects in ruby. `{}` is not "nothing", it is an empty [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html).

Comment: What ridiculous code! Wouldn't pass my code review.

Answer (score 6):

1. `reduce` is called with an empty hash. This means that the value of `acc` in the first call to the block will be `{}`.
2. In Ruby, the last statement within a function is the return value, so the block returns `acc`.

You probably need to read what `reduce` does exactly to understand this code.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. There's nothing passed into `reduce`. What does that mean?

That's not true. There is a positional argument `{}` passed into `reduce` as well as a block.

But even if nothing were passed, what's the big deal? There's nothing being passed into `to_s` either, yet somehow that doesn't seem to bother you.

> 2. There's a single `acc`. What does that mean?

It means the same thing as the `acc` on the line before: dereference the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation for `reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

The first argument (`{}`) is the initial parameter of `acc`, `acc` is what it will be returned when `reduce` finishes.

It is just transforming the array into a hash, the final result is:

```
{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"}
```